# How to make pages / post from jekyll data

Tags: content-management-system, jekyll, contentful

I am trying to use contentful with jekyll, I have Article data model giving all the articles in a yaml format.

```
---
article:
- sys:
    id: 4xHyK0wA48sKiQeO8WK4CU
  title: Another Awesome Article
  body: |-
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur esse debitis, voluptatibus excepturi quos cumque, incidunt laborum ullam quo. Dignissimos magni tempora officiis nisi, doloremque quisquam natus iure aspernatur quos.
    Repellendus et dolorem hic officiis, excepturi asperiores! Officia hic deleniti deserunt repudiandae vero, odit ab dicta pariatur facere debitis fuga dolore, sint, minima. Ad modi incidunt suscipit, velit obcaecati enim.
- sys:
    id: 6Ju73rzJS0WQIKuS0mso62
  title: Awesome title
  body: |-
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur esse debitis, voluptatibus excepturi quos cumque, incidunt laborum ullam quo. Dignissimos magni tempora officiis nisi, doloremque quisquam natus iure aspernatur quos.
    Repellendus et dolorem hic officiis, excepturi asperiores! Officia hic deleniti deserunt repudiandae vero, odit ab dicta pariatur facere debitis fuga dolore, sint, minima. Ad modi incidunt suscipit, velit obcaecati enim.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur esse debitis, voluptatibus excepturi quos cumque, incidunt laborum ullam quo. Dignissimos magni tempora officiis nisi, doloremque quisquam natus iure aspernatur quos.
    Repellendus et dolorem hic officiis, excepturi asperiores! Officia hic deleniti deserunt repudiandae vero, odit ab dicta pariatur facere debitis fuga dolore, sint, minima. Ad modi incidunt suscipit, velit obcaecati enim.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur esse debitis, voluptatibus excepturi quos cumque, incidunt laborum ullam quo. Dignissimos magni tempora officiis nisi, doloremque quisquam natus iure aspernatur quos.
    Repellendus et dolorem hic officiis, excepturi asperiores! Officia hic deleniti deserunt repudiandae vero, odit ab dicta pariatur facere debitis fuga dolore, sint, minima. Ad modi incidunt suscipit, velit obcaecati enim.
```

How can I create individual page / post through this data and convert to static files in jekyll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen to generate a page from each element in the array. There are other few plugins with similar behaviour that might fit your needs better.

This is something that Jekyll does not support out of the box.